# Qt creator (mac) crashes while opening .ui file

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

When I try to open a .ui form in Qt Creator, it crashes.
Here's some strings from a crash report:

> Application Specific Information:
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc:
>   std::bad_alloc abort() called

Does anyone know what to do? If so, help me out, please.

Comment: Qt bugs can be filed here: https://bugreports.qt.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the solution:
I have reinstalled the OS and Qt with all its parts works properly.
If someone has the same problem and has a Time Machine archive, do not restore from it, 'cause if you do, the bug will remain. Instead of that, install OS X and then restore files from Finder, if necessary.